# Array solo imprime ultimo registro php

Tags: php

Esta es la funcion principal

```
function report_details($display = null) {

$sql="SELECT * FROM inventario where ubicacion = 'Bodega'";
        function filterTable($sql)
        {
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto");
            $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            return $filter_Result;
        }
        $search_result = filterTable($sql);

        


if($display){
    $imagePath =  "../fotos/";
} else {
    $imagePath = "../fotos/";
}
```

la variable $reportdetails solo me muestra el ultimo valor no muestra todo los valores de la base de datos

```
while($row = $search_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
$reportdetails= array(

    array('ID' => $row['id_inventario'],'Nombre' => $row['nombre'],'Descripcion' =>  $row['descripcion'],'Precio' => $row['precio'],'Cantidad en inventario' =>  $row['cantidad'],'Orden de Compra' => $row['orden_compra'],'Fecha de Compra' => $row['fecha_compra'],'Ubicación' => $row['ubicacion'],'¿Herramienta Reparada?' => $row['reparada'],'Fotos     ' => $imagePath . $row['fotos'])
  
);

} return $reportdetails;
  
}
```

Mas adelante yo llamo la funcion reportdetails y solo muestra el ultimo valor

Comment: `$reportdetails[]=  array('ID' => $row['id_inventario'], ........)` Prueba con eso

Answer (score 0):

pasa que estas matando el array, ya que no le indicas que se sobrescriba ... fijate

```
function report_details($display = null) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventario where ubicacion = 'Bodega'";

    /* No es necesario crear esta funcion 
    function filterTable($sql)
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        return $filter_Result;
    }
    $search_result = filterTable($sql);
    */
    
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto");
    $search_result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    /* Esto no tiene sentido porque simpre $imagePath =  "../fotos/";
    if ($display) {
        $imagePath =  "../fotos/";
    } else {
        $imagePath = "../fotos/";
    }
    */

    $reportdetails = array(); //Creas la variable como un array 
    while ($row = $search_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        /* $imagePath Deberia ser */
        $imagePath = $display??"../fotos/". $row['fotos'];

        array_push($reportdetails, //Vas agregando los sub array que se vayan creando
            array( //estas creando una array de cada fila que se recoja
                'ID' => $row['id_inventario'], 
                'Nombre' => $row['nombre'], 
                'Descripcion' =>  $row['descripcion'], 
                'Precio' => $row['precio'], 
                'Cantidad en inventario' =>  $row['cantidad'], 
                'Orden de Compra' => $row['orden_compra'], 
                'Fecha de Compra' => $row['fecha_compra'], 
                'Ubicación' => $row['ubicacion'], 
                '¿Herramienta Reparada?' => $row['reparada'], 
                'Fotos' => $imagePath
            )
        );
        //while repite el ciclo y comenzamos de nuevo, hasta detenerse 
    }
    return $reportdetails;
}
```

Saludos